# React Native vs Native

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, react-native

Добрых времени суток.

Решил начать изучать мобильную разработку, а конкретно разработку под iOS (Swift, Objective-C), после долгих лет работы frontend-разработчиком на Native JS & React и появился вопрос, что же лучше? React Native или Swift?

В интернете статьи пишут лишь про *производительность* и быстроту разработки, так таковой, в принципе, это логично, что компании/агенству легче содержать 1-го человека, который *воюет на 2 фронта сразу*, в следствии чего 2 приложения (Android, iOS) выпускаются быстрее, нежели, чем на нативных языках, ибо там уже *нужно 2-а разработчика*, соответственно, платить таким людям нужно не мало, но если абстрагироваться от денег и скорости разработки, сделать упор на качество, производительность и лёгкую поддержку приложения, что же будет лучше?

Могу предположить следующий фактор, если приложение легковесное само по себе, то, наверно, React-native, ибо получится быстрее выпустить 2 приложения, но если приложение уже *имеет вес*, то, скорее всего, нативные ЯП для соответствующей платформы.

*убираем фактор покупки соответствующей машины для iOS, которая стоит не малых денег

**очень интересно почитать мнения разработчиков react-native и разработчиков iOS/Android

***если вы долго пишите на Swift/Objective-C или Java, то, пожалуйста, распишите, почему именно этот стэк? почему не выбрали/перешли на react-native? Что по Вашему мнению изменится, если Вы поменяете текущий стэк технологий? (убирая фактор поддержки старых приложений)

****полное абстрагирование от компаний и денег

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит сугубо от проекта и от компании.
Кросс платформа идеально подходит для старта проекта. Так как позволяет писать код сразу для двух платформ. 
Для больших проектов и Enterprise - Нативная разработка сильное предпочтительнее, но и тут зависит от проекта внутри компании. У нас несколько команд по мобильной разработке и например внутренние проекты пишут на кроссплатформе, клиентские проекты, где пользователей больше - пишутся на нативе.

> ***если вы долго пишите на Swift/Objective-C или Java, то, пожалуйста, распишите, почему именно этот стэк? почему не выбрали/перешли на
>   react-native? Что по Вашему мнению изменится, если Вы поменяете
>   текущий стэк технологий? (убирая фактор поддержки старых приложений)

Я начинал писать на Android, когда еще не было Android Studio и кроме как на Java, писать было не на чем. Только недавно кроссплатформа стала не отличаться по Performance c Native. Сейчас пишу под iOS на Swift. Кроссплатформой никогда не занимался, если и буду заниматься, только если это будет Flutter.
Ну и интеграция Enterprise Библиотек в нативе происходит проще, например некоторые библиотеки, которые еще написаны на Obj-C и я сомневаюсь, что их будут переносить на Swift.